# rollback transaction error rails from google geocoding api

Tags: google-api, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to create a review form in my rails app but when i click on the submit button,  the form cannot be submitted.When i lookup the error in the terminal and i get this error. i searched the error but couldn't find any solution. did anyone had this issue before?:

```
Google API error: over query limit.
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

**Update**

I am not only getting the Google API error. sometimes i get this error and other time i only get  rollback transaction only.

**This is the Reviews Controller:**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  # check if logged in
  before_action :check_login, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    # this is our list page for our reviews
    @price = params[:price]
    @cuisine = params[:cuisine]
    @location = params[:location]


    # start with all the reviews
    @reviews = Review.all

    # filtering by price
    if @price.present?
      @reviews = @reviews.where(price: @price)
    end

    # filter by cuisine
    if @cuisine.present?
      @reviews = @reviews.where(cuisine: @cuisine)
    end

    # search near the location
    if @location.present?
      @reviews = @reviews.near(@location)
    end

  end

  def new
    # the form for adding a new review
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def create
    # take info from the form and add it to the model
    @review = Review.new(form_params)

    # and then associate it with a user
    @review.user = @current_user

    # we want to check if the model can be saved
    # if it is, we're go the home page again
    # if it isn't, show the new form
    if @review.save
      flash[:succces] = "Your review was posted!"

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      # show the view for new.html.erb
      render "new"
    end

  end

  def show
    # individual review page
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end


  def destroy
    # find the individual review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])

    # destroy if they have access
    if @review.user == @current_user
      @review.destroy
    end

    # redirect to the home page
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def edit
    # find the individual review (to edit)
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])

    if @review.user != @current_user
      redirect_to root_path
    elsif @review.created_at < 4.hours.ago
      redirect_to review_path(@review)
    end
  end

  def update
    # find the individual review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])

    if @review.user != @current_user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      # update with the new info from the form
      if @review.update(form_params)

        # redirect somewhere new
        redirect_to review_path(@review)
      else
        render "edit"
      end
    end
  end

  def form_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:title, :restaurant, :body, :score,
      :ambiance, :cuisine, :price, :address)
  end

end
```

**This is the  Review form page:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :restaurant %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.input :cuisine %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.input :score %>
  <%= f.input :ambiance %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**The Review Model**

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord

  # add an association that has a 1-to-many relationship
  has_many :comments
  has_many :bookmarks

  # add an association to the user
  belongs_to :user

  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode


  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :score, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 10 }
  validates :restaurant, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true

  def to_param
    id.to_s + "-" + title.parameterize
  end

end
```

**This is My Schema file**

```
  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "score"
    t.string "restaurant"
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "cuisine"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "ambiance"
    t.text "address"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. you are going over Google's Geocoding API quota as evidenced by the error message "over query limit"
2. Most likely because of that, your model cannot be saved is rolled back. The geocoding API call fails, it doesn't save.

I would check the Google API Console and see if you have actually hit their quota (possible if you're running multiple tests and you're on their free tier of service). If you have not hit the limit, file a support request with Google API.

Answer (score 0):

You probably reached your Google API quota.

In model you have `geocoded_by ...` that is used by `gem geocoder` so have a look at that.

Google has per second limit as well as per day limit [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)

Comment: yes but i didn't even reach 10 reviews post. i don't think i overreached the limit .